# image div jQuery emits white box on Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

Changing the width and height of the galleria style seems to change the way the white is shown. I have very very basic html and css knowledge hence the use of galleria. If I expand the style to the point where the bottom thumbnails are slightly hidden the images seem to appear without any white boxes. The code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<div class="wrapper">
<head>
<style>
body 
{
background-image:url('Assets/light_background.jpg');
}
</style>
    <style>
   .galleria{ 
width:1100px; height: 600px; background: #000; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding: 0; 
"Content-Length"
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    }
    </style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="galleria/galleria-1.3.5.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> JC Portfolio </title>
<link href="Styles/portfolio_cascadesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div  class="header">
    <a href="home.html"><img src="Assets/logo.png" alt="JC logo" width="130px" height="130px" align="left"></a>
</div> 
<div class="menu" align="right">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html" target="_self">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="photoshop.html" target="_self">Photoshop designs</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" target="_self">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
        <br style="clear:left"/>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="galleria" margin-bottom: 0;>
<img src="photoshop_images/Ending_dayZ_dvd_cover.jpg">
<img src="photoshop_images/FireStormMenu.jpg">
<img src="photoshop_images/goku_apocalyptic_wallpaper.jpg">
<img src="photoshop_images/DBZ_bookmark.jpg">
<img src="photoshop_images/THCG-Black.jpg">
</div>
<script>
Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
Galleria.run('.galleria');
</script>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's done well sorry http://jsfiddle.net/JxCpV/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. When you say that the "white" changes, what do you mean by the white? The white around the sides of the entire website (like left and ride)? If you want the galleria to be the same width as the header (logo and navigation links), change `.galleria { width: 1100px; }` to `.galleria { width: 100%; }`. You may need to adjust the `height` attribute as well, but that will depend on the pictures you put into the galleria.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/4be565e260be73ecfbc4e392b136003a , it's fairly random since if I scroll down all that remains that isn't white are the thumbnails. And the last image is the only one that can appear

Comment: Based off the picture you've uploaded/shared, it looks like you have some CSS that is making your main container (below the header) that wide. If the site is available online, please post a link and I'll continue to help you figure out your spacing/width issue. Just based off the HTML fragment you original posted, there is some cleanup that needs to happen.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't, is there some other way?

Comment: you should try and get with me, or someone else, offline this thread. Your galleria and other layout likely needs some refactoring. If you can private message or chat, we can share information and go from there.

Comment: It would be helpful if I could get in touch with you but there's nothing that shows me details, I need an email or something if you could message it to me.